# Assigning values to elements in 3x3 array

Tags: python, arrays

```
colors = [['#01002b' '#01012b' '#01022b']
         ['#11032b' '#11042b' '#11052b']
         ['#21062b' '#21072b' '#21082b']]
```

I made sudoku solver and now want to make GUI with tkinter for it. So every 3x3 element has to have different color. Whole board is 9x9 for better explanation it should look like this.

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5],
[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5],
[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5],
[6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8],
[6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8],
[6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8]
```

Where each number represents different color.

I tried

```
for i in range(81):
    tkinter.Label(
        text=grid[i//9][i%9],
        bg=colors[i//27][i//27],
        fg="orange",
        font=("Courier", 44)
        ).grid(row=i//9, column=i%9)
```

and other variations but I am missing something.

So if I try bg=colors[i//27][i//27] I ll get something like this

[image]

As you see every 9x3 has different color and only 3 colors used. I want 3x3 and all 9 colors from list.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: I want for every 3x3 cube to assign different color (element) from list `colors`

Comment: Might be easier to work with `numpy` [array slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Maybe now it will be much clear